# mysql won't start in Fedora, no error logs

Tags: mysql, fedora

I'm having a devil of a time trying to get mysql to start on a Fedora install.

Whenever I try to start it i get:

```
[root@server1 log]# service mysqld start
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl  start mysqld.service
Job failed. See system logs and 'systemctl status' for details.
```

Then when I do a systemctl query I get:

```
[root@server1 log]# systemctl status mysqld.service
mysqld.service - MySQL database server
  Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; enabled)
  Active: failed since Sat, 18 Aug 2012 21:06:48 -0400; 1min 59s ago
 Process: 747 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mysqld-prepare-db-dir (code=exited, status=254)
  CGroup: name=systemd:/system/mysqld.service
```

The funny part is when I check /var/log/mysqld.log, there's absolutely nothing there

Update. I did mysql_install_db (Was I even supposed to do this?) and now here is what my error log looks like:

```
120818 22:29:36 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib$
120818 22:29:36 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
^G/usr/libexec/mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm' (errno: 13)
120818 22:29:36 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upg$
120818 22:29:36 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
120818 22:29:36 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
120818 22:29:36 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.5
120818 22:29:36 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
^G/usr/libexec/mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/tmp/ibvxiFII' (Errcode: 13)
120818 22:29:36  InnoDB: Error: unable to create temporary file; errno: 13
120818 22:29:36 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
120818 22:29:36 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
120818 22:29:36 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
120818 22:29:36 [ERROR] Aborting

120818 22:29:36 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

^G/usr/libexec/mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm' (errno: 13)
120818 22:36:34 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upg$
120818 22:36:34 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
120818 22:36:34 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
120818 22:36:34 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.5
120818 22:36:34 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
^G/usr/libexec/mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/tmp/ibnO07sQ' (Errcode: 13) 
120818 22:36:34  InnoDB: Error: unable to create temporary file; errno: 13
120818 22:36:34 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
120818 22:36:34 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
120818 22:36:34 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
120818 22:36:34 [ERROR] Aborting

120818 22:36:34 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

120818 22:36:34 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid end$
```

Comment: What about /var/log/mysqld.err? I'd also run `yum update` to ensure that you're not being affected by an old SELinux bug.

Comment: Off topic; belongs on [sf]

Comment: @Vic SELinux is disabled. And I don't have a /var/log/mysqld.err

Comment: Can you post output of df -h?

Comment: For some reason Fedora controls the majority of services through something called systemd. Mysql wasn't getting installed there for some reason. Instead of trying to figure out another flavor of linux, I just went ahead and reinstalled Ubuntu on my VPS which I'm more familiar with. Anyone reading this thread can disregard it, as I'm no longer on Fedora.